# How I can Create a material, select it, create new nodes with this material and Animate them?

Tags: python, nodes, blender

i'm looking for a way to create a new Material and Select it, to create nodes in this Material and animate the values in those nodes.
This is the code that I actually have:

```
mat = bpy.ops.material.new()
mat_nodes = bpy.data.materials['USDiscoMaterial'].node_tree.nodes
```

But actually, with this code Blender will rename the current material with "USDiscoMaterial", and creates a new one but not select it.
And if I want to create a node in this material?

Comment: For blender specific questions you should get more feedback at [blender.stackexchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com) - you may also find some of your questions exist there.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new material that uses nodes (for cycles) with -

```
mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name='USDiscoMaterial')
mat.use_nodes = True
mat_nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
mat_links = mat.node_tree.links
# a new material node tree already has a diffuse and material output node
output = mat_nodes['Material Output']
diffuse = mat_nodes['Diffuse BSDF']
```

To add a new node you use `node_tree.nodes.new('type')` where the list of available node types can be found [on this page](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.ShaderNode.html). Most nodes store their editable values within the input sockets used to connect nodes. If a node has values without an input connection you can find the property names in the api reference for each node.

```
noise = mat_nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexNoise')
noise.inputs['Detail'].default_value = 5.0
cur_frame = bpy.context.scene.frame_current
noise.inputs['Detail'].keyframe_insert('default_value', frame=cur_frame)
```

Fort the material to work you also need to add links between the nodes -

```
mat_links.new(noise.outputs['Color'], diffuse.inputs['Color'])
```

After checking that there is an available material slot in the object you can assign the material to the object.

```
obj = bpy.context.active_object
if len(obj.material_slots) == 0:
    bpy.ops.object.material_slot_add()

obj.material_slots[0].material = mat
```

Comment: And if I want to add a noise modifier?

Comment: The same as I commented on your [other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36116085/blender-pythonhow-can-i-animate-the-factor-value-in-the-mix-node-with-python/36123834#comment60021839_36123834)